# BackgroundWorker RunWorkerCompleted not executed on UI thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm, backgroundworker

I have written a small wrapper around BackgroundWorker:

```cs
public class Worker
{
  public void Execute<T>(Func<T> work, Action<Exception, T> workCompleted)
  {
    var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += (o, ea) => { ea.Result = work(); };
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, ea) => { workCompleted(ea.Error, (T)ea.Result); };
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
  }
}
```

I use it in the viewmodel (which is created in XAML) like so:

```cs
public class MainWindowViewmodel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private ObservableCollection<Job> _jobs = new ObservableCollection<Job>();
  public ICollectionView JobsView { get; } = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_jobs);
  public RelayCommand RefreshJobsCommand => new RelayCommand(x => UpdateJobs()); /*edit1*/

  private void UpdateJobs() /*executed via command binding*/
  {
    new Worker().Execute(() => _webServiceManager.JobService.GetJobsByDate(settings.Limit, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-365)), (ex, jobArray) =>
      {
        jobArray.toList().ForEach(j=>_jobs.Add(j));
      });
  }
}
```

When jobs are added in `workCompleted` to ObservableCollection `_jobs`, I get the following exception:
`This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.`

So obviously the `RunWorkerCompleted` callback doesn't run on the UI thread. But as far as I know it should run on the one thread from which `RunWorkerAsync` was called? And this should be the UI thread, since it is called from inside the viewmodel (which was created from XAML) from a command binding (also UI thread), right?

What am I missing here?

**Edit2:**
I could narrow down the problem to the initial loading of jobs. This is done from the ctor of `MainWindow` and will result in the described problem. Any additional updates afterwards using the UI button via command binding work absolutely fine.

So the problem is, on initial loading, `MainWindow` ctor, `ViewModel` ctor and `Worker.Execute()` are executed on the UI thread, but `workCompleted` is not, although the `SynchronizationContext` should be set to the UI thread at the moment of invoking `RunWorkerAsync`.

Whenever the next loading is triggered via command binding, the `workCompleted` is also set to the `SynchronizationContext` of the UI thread.

Any idea why this isn't working in the first place?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   private MainWindowViewmodel _viewmodel;

   public MainWindow(Connection connection)
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      Debug.WriteLine("mainwindow-ctor: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());
      _viewmodel = (MainWindowViewmodel)DataContext;
      _viewmodel.UpdateJobs();
   }
}
```

Comment: Do not use BackgroundWorker. Use tasks and async/await

Comment: What does `GetJobsByDate()` do? How does it ensure that the lambda you pass it is executed on the ui thread? I mean `_webServiceManager` does not sound that synchronous.

Comment: Are you really calling `UpdateJobs()` on the UI thread? Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: The **external** component `_webServiceManager` is implemented synchronously so I would have to wrap all the calls into a Task.Run(), which is imho not so nice.

Comment: @mm8 I added the code for the command bound to by a UI button. This will fire to execute `UpdateJobs()` which should still be the UI thread...?

Comment: It's impossible to say how your command is called by just looking at the property definition. If it's invoked from a UI element in a running app, it should be called from *a* UI thread though. There may be several dispatcher threads in an application though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by moving the initial loading of the jobs from the `MainWindow` constructor to the `MainWindow.Loaded` event.

For some reason the BackgroundWorker doesn't have the `SynchronizationContext` on the UI thread for `RunWorkerCompleted` unless the UI is fully initialized.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   private MainWindowViewmodel _viewmodel;

   public MainWindow(Connection connection)
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      _viewmodel = (MainWindowViewmodel)DataContext;
      Loaded += MainWindowLoaded;
   }

   private void MainWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      _viewmodel.UpdateJobs();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The thread on which the `RunWokerCompleted` event is handled is determined by `SynchronizationContext.Current` property at the time the `RunWorkerAsync` method is called.

So if your `Execute` method is actually called on the UI thread in a WPF application, where the `SynchronizationContext.Current` property returns a `DispatcherSynchronizationContext`, `workCompleted` will be invoked on this thread as well. You easily can confirm this yourself by calling `Execute()` in the constructor of the `MainWindow`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        new Worker().Execute(() => { Thread.Sleep(5000); return 0; }, (ex, jobArray) =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());
        });
    }
}
```

By the way, the [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl) is the preferred way to write multithreaded and parallel code since .NET Framework 4. The task asynchronous programming model (TAP) and the `async` and `await` keywords that were introdued in .NET 4.5 make it even easier to use.

Comment: I added some output of the thread id as shown in your example. The interesting thing is: mainwindow ctor, viewmodel ctor, Worker.Execute() => all have the same thread id. So `RunWorkerAsync` is called from this exact thread. Only in the `workComplete` delegate, the thread id is different

Comment: @Matthias: Did you check the value of `SynchronizationContext.Current`?

Comment: I compared `SynchronizationContext.Current` with equals in the same places as before and the result is identical. Context is equal in mainWindow, viewModel and Worker.Execute() but its a different context in `workComplete` delegate